# How does Google Analytics Real Time work?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, comet, long-polling

I'm wondering how Google Analytics Real Time user interface works, what's the technique ? Do they use long-polling from the client to keep the UI statistics instantly up to date by delivering realtime information from the server to the client?
I just open Chrome dev tool on network tab and there is a infinite request on https://www.google.com/analytics/realtime/bind
Does anybody know the trick? It works flawless...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The below refers to how the real time data is collected, not how the UI updates.** *(It looks like the UI is just using AJAX polling on the client-side, though)*

No special polling or client-side technique is used. Data collection is the same as it always has been.

Instead, Google Analytics will assume that someone who's triggered a pageview in the last 5 minutes is still an "active" visitor.

[From e-nor:](http://www.e-nor.com/blog/index.php/web-analytics/google-analytics-real-time-wait-no-more/)

> These visitors have been active in the last 5 minutes, any one not active for over 5 minutes is dropped.

Comment: I see this question has been accepted but I think the question is actually asking how does the Google Analytics Realtime UI work. Not about data collection.

Comment: Oh, ha, nice close reading. Oops. My post is the correct answer to a different question. Will edit to reflect.

Answer (score 2):

I was one of two people who built the first version of the Realtime Analytics UI. We used Closure's [BrowserChannel](https://code.google.com/p/closure-library/source/browse/closure/goog/net/browserchannel.js).