# How does google analytics track user exit

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have been checking google analytics. they track user exit very efficiently.

I had written a code to process some server side code on window's onbeforeunload event to keep a track of when has the user closed the browser, but that was very unreliable, the script wasn't fired everytime.

What method does google use to efficiently track this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my understanding it doesn't.
It only tracks new pageviews.

Therefore the time a user is on a page A is measured by the time in between the time he started viewing page A and the time he started viewing page B.
Therefore Google can't measure the time you spent on page B (if that's the last page you visited).

More info on the GA help page about [Time on Page](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1006924)

**UPDATE** A real time visit ends when a user hasn't been active in the last 5 minutes. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8330780/how-does-google-analytics-real-time-works)

Comment: They do track user exits in the real-time version which they have just released.

Comment: I just used Wireshark to capture any traffic. I'm quite sure no information is sent when a user exits a page. They must do their Real Time graphs server side.

Comment: I just updated my answer with a new found resource on GA real time

Answer (score 0):

I do not really know how google does it but the simplest solution is probably to time stamp then user load the site and then he left clicks on a link without your domain  name and which target is not `_blank`.
Of course there are the all mighty cookies they simply watch then your page is closed but not everybody lets their browsers eat them :)